# reactjs) how can i keep current input value of component when re-render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I developing front-end with reactjs recently.
but i have a problem in my SPA project.
my webapp have tab menu like a text-editor.
I want each tab to always keep their input value. However, these values are lost because tabs are re-rendering when they disappear or are new.
Is there a way to keep these values without using storage like local-storage?

Comment: Seeking clarity in your question. How are you writing your react component? Are you using class components or functional components...

Comment: i use funtion component.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to take advantage of the useState hook to store an object that contains the data from your tabs... so you can get the data from the object whenever the state changes... assuming you don't update it wrongly.

Find illustratio below:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

function MyTabComponent (props){
   const [tabData, updateTabData] = useState({})

   return(
   // your component jsx here
   // you can then fetch your tab data from the tabData object
   )
}
```

Hoping you find this helpful.